# UrfFetchApp.fetch error with google map direction url with waypoints (waypoint separated by |)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I use Google map direction on my Google Apps Script (GAS).
This program create a url:

```
function createUrl(origin, destination,wayPoint) {
          var Your_API_KEY = "my code here";
          var serviceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" 
          +"origin="+origin
          +"&destination="+destination
          +"&waypoints=optimize:true|"+ wayPoint
          +"&mode="+Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING
          +"&alternatives="+Boolean(0)
          +"&key="+Your_API_KEY;
         return(serviceUrl);
        }
```

and use UrlFetchApp.fetch() in GAS to get result.

```
function test () {
          var origin = "6501 Dresden Ln, Raleigh, NC 27612, USA";
          var destination = "5000 Capital Blvd, Raleigh, NC 27616, USA ";
          var items = ["7928 Mandrel Way, Raleigh, NC 27616, USA"];         
          var waypoints = createWayPoint(items);
          var serviceUrl = createUrl(origin,destination,waypoints);
          Logger.log (serviceUrl);
          var options= {
            muteHttpExceptions:true,
            contentType: "application/json",
          };

          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl,options); //ERROR HERE
          if(response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            var directions = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
            if (directions !== null){
             // do something;
            }
          }
        }
```

The serviceUrl like that:

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=6501 Dresden Ln, Raleigh, NC 27612, USA&destination=5000 Capital Blvd, Raleigh, NC 27616, USA &waypoints=7928 Mandrel Way, Raleigh, NC 27616, USA | 6501 Dresden Ln, Raleigh, NC 27612&mode=driving&alternatives=false&key= MyKeyCodeHere"

I can use this serviceUrl to **get result manual in the browser**. But UrlFetchApp.fetch() can not.

I found that if serviceUrl has not "|", it can work. But I need multi waypoints and it separated by "|" in Url (I want to use many waypoints - near 23 waypoints - so I need | in the Url). See about waypoints: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

```
// multi waypoints separated by |.
    function createWayPoint (arrayWayPoint){
      var waypoints = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayWayPoint.length; i++) {
        var address = arrayWayPoint[i];
        if (address !== "") {
          if (i==0){
            waypoints = arrayWayPoint[0];
          }
          else {
            waypoints = waypoints + " | " + arrayWayPoint[i];
          }
        }
      }
      return waypoints;
    }
```

Anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. But one reason I can think of that might cause `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` not to load your page is due to spaces in your url. [Try encoding your url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183817/google-apps-script-urlfetch-encoding-url)

Comment: Thank for your answer. 

This Url still can work it has not "|" (has space but not |).

I tried encoder it by encodeURIComponent(serviceUrl); but it can not work.

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `encodeURIComponent()` to the place like following sample?

#### Sample script :

```
function createUrl(origin, destination,wayPoint) {
  var Your_API_KEY = "my code here";
  var serviceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" 
  +"origin="+encodeURIComponent(origin)
  +"&destination="+encodeURIComponent(destination)
  +"&waypoints=" + encodeURIComponent("optimize:true|"+ wayPoint)
  +"&mode="+Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING
  +"&alternatives="+Boolean(0)
  +"&key="+Your_API_KEY;
  return(serviceUrl);
}
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.